# ¿Cómo guardo un conjunto de parámetros y resultados de un bucle for?

Tags: r

Tengo un bucle que trabaja en función de dos variables a y b. Este bucle me da variables respuesta que son c, d y e. Pruebo con diferentes valores para las variables a y b, lo que quiero es guardar las variables respuesta que obtengo cada vez que ejecuto el bucle.

Realice el siguiente código pero solo pude guardar las primeras variables respuesta:

```
saveRDS(paste(a,b,c,d,e),file=paste("exer.RData"))
readRDS(file="exer.RData")
```

Creo que lo mejor seria realizar un bucle que me guarde los resultados de forma continua, intenté esto:

```
res<-paste(a,b,c,d,e)
for(i in 1:length(res)){
  saveRDS(i,file=paste0(names(res[i]),".rda"))}
```

Pero no me funciona y sólo se guarda los primeros resultados de la primera vez que ejecuto el bucle. La escritura de los resultados debe ir al mismo fichero antes de que empiece con el siguiente juego de parámetros.

También intenté otra forma:

```
res<-apply(res,1,paste,collapse=",")
for(i in 1:length(res)) { 
 store<-res[i] 
 saveRDS(store,file=paste(res[i],".rda")) }
```

Pero al ejecutar `readRDS(".rda")`, sólo tengo los resultados del primer juego de parámetros.

Comment: Bienvenida Katherine Daniela Arias Huaman a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exploremos un poco las opciones que tienes para exportar los objetos con `saveRDS()`, primero, está función espera que le pase un objeto, no una cadena con el nombre del mismo, por lo que la forma más básica sería:

```
saveRDS(a, file="a.rda"); a <- readRDS("a.rda")
saveRDS(b, file="b.rda"); b <- readRDS("b.rda")
saveRDS(c, file="c.rda"); c <- readRDS("c.rda")
```

Agrego la relectura para cerrar el ciclo. Esto claro, puede ser tedioso si tienes muchos objetos a salvar (y no quieres salvar el entorno completo, que por cierto es peligroso), la alternativa, es usar una lista:

```
variables <- list(a=a, b=b, c=c) # agregamos el nombre a cada elemento
saveRDS(variables, file="variables.rda")
variables <- readRDS("variables.rda")

a <- variables$a    # accedemos por nombre
a <- variables[[1]] # accedemos for índice
```

En el caso de una lista, finalmente salvas un conjunto de objetos en un único archivo, lo cual es bastante más cómodo. Puedes ver en el ejemplo, como luego accedemos a cada variable de forma individual. También, podrías leer la lista del archivo y recuperar cargar los objetos individuales  directamente usando:

```
attach(readRDS("variables.rda"))
```

Pero, con cuidado, por que esto agrega un nuevo `environment` y si no estás familiarizado puede eventualmente complicarte un poco.

Por último, si quieres salvar todo en un ciclo `for` tradicional, podrías hacer algo así:

```
for (variable in list(a=a, b=b, c=c)) {
  saveRDS(variable, file = paste0(quote(a),".rda"))
}
```

Iteramos sobre la lista de objetos y salvamos cada uno, con `paste0(quote(a),".rda")` logramos construir el nombre del archivo para que se `<nombre de objeto>.rda`

Comment: Gracias @Patricio, me has ayudado mucho. El bucle me funciona bien, sólo que al cambiar el grupo de parámetros (a,b,c,d) y ejecutar en un bucle que tengo programado, me da nuevos resultados y estos no los guarda en el mismo file, sólo me aparecen los de el primer grupo ejecutado. Espero puedas ayudarme.

Comment: Por ejemplo, luego de ejecutar el bucle por primera vez, tengo estos resultados `0.2   10   0.53   -0.37   0.33`. Al ejecutarlo una segunda vez, obtengo estos resultados `0.1   10   0.68    -0.42   0.27`, y así sucesivamente van cambiando los valores. Entonces, esto es lo que quiero que se guarde secuencialmente en un mismo file. Espero puedas ayudarme @Patricio. Muchas gracias!

Comment: @KatherineDanielaAriasHuaman, es decir que vas generando distintos valores (como si fueran distintas versiones) y quieres salvar todas estas? Si es así, trabaja directamente con una sola lista a la que vas agregando cada conjunto de valore y por último salvas todos.

Comment: gracias por responder. Es el mismo código, sólo cambiaría las variables. Creo que es necesario hacer un bucle para que se guarde secuencialmente ya que cada vez que vuelvo a dar un valor a las variables, el environment queda en cero. Trabajé con una lista, pero cada vez que vuelvo a ejecutar nuevos parámetros los nuevos resultados se sobreponen sobre los anteriores.

Answer (score 0):

Para guardar más de un objeto mejor usar `save`. Te sirve esto?

```
save(list=c(a,b,c,d,e), "exer.RData")
```

También tienes muchos `paste` que no acabo de entender, para hacer un conjunto de objetos mejor usar `c()`

espero que te sirva!

Comment: Alfonso, sería una buena idea que explicaras con un poco más de detalle por qué es mejor usar `save` o `c()`. Así, tu respuesta quedaría más completa y mucho más fácil de entender.

Comment: Gracias @Alfonso. Lo que sucede es que quiero guardar varias veces esos valores de la lista (a,b,c,d,e) ya que estos cambian y quiero guardarlos de forma secuencial (cada vez que yo ejecute nuevos valores para los parámetros)