# ¿Cómo contar y separar valores de un dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

Tengo el siguiente `data.frame` de genes que tiene más de 100 mil valores y se encuentran según la columna total entre valores de 221 y 213 (es decir hay valores para: 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220 y 221)

```
            mix total
1      A2M-ACTB   221
2     A2M-ACTG1   221
3     A2M-ANXA1   221
4       A2M-APP   221
5       A2M-B2M   221
6      A2M-CD24   221
7      A2M-CD74   221
8    A2M-COL1A2   221
9    A2M-COL3A1   221
10      A2M-DSP   221
11   A2M-EEF1A1   221
12     A2M-ENO1   221
13      A2M-FN1   221
14    A2M-GAPDH   221
15    A2M-HLA-B   221
16 A2M-HSP90AB1   221
17      A2M-MGP   221
18   A2M-RPL13A   221
19     A2M-RPS6   221
20   A2M-TM4SF1   221
```

Y lo que quisiera primeramente es contar que el número de filas de genes que presentan 221, luego 220, y así sucesivamente hasta el 213. Posteriormente quisiera separar en objetos individuales cada conteo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La función `tapply()` permite aplicar una función a los valores de una variable de acuerdo a las categorías de otra variable. En este caso, la función que podemos aplicar para contar las categorías en `total` es  `length()`.

```
# datos de ejemplo
nrows <- ceiling(seq(100,250, length = 14))
genes <- data.frame(
mix = replicate(sum(nrows), expr =  paste0(sample(x = letters,size = 7, 
                                                  replace = T), collapse = "")),
total = rep(c(212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220,221,222,234,1000,10), 
    times = nrows))
genes

# conteo
conteo <- tapply(X = genes$mix ,INDEX = genes$total , FUN = length)

conteo[as.character(c(213:221))]
213 214 215 216 217 218 219 220 221 
112 124 135 147 158 170 181 193 204
```

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola!

Pongo como ejemplo el conjunto de datos `iris` y a continuación indico cómo se realizaría con tu conjunto de datos.

**1) Con el conjunto de datos `iris`**

```
# Cargar los datos
  data("iris")
  
# Separar por nombre de "Species"
  data.sep <- split(iris, iris$Species)
  
# Número de casos para cada variable
  lapply(data.sep, nrow)
  table(iris$Species)
```

**2) Con tus datos (siendo `data` su nombre)**

```
# 2.1) Separar por nombre de "total"
  data.sep <- split(data, data$Stotal)
  
# 2.2) Número de casos para cada variable
  lapply(data.sep, nrow)

# 2.2.b) Número de casos para cada variable (en tabla)
  table(data$total)
```

Por si eres usuario nuevo, explico un poco qué hace cada paso:

- El paso 2.1) genera un objeto tipo "lista" con tantos elementos como valores distintos para la variable `total`
- El paso 2.2) calcula para cada elemento de la lista anterior, mediante la función `nrow()` el número de filas de esa sub-matriz, es decir, el número de genes que tienen el mismo valor para  la variable `total`
- El paso 2.2.b) realiza lo mismo que el paso 2.2 pero genera una tabla en la que te indica el número de casos para cada uno de los distintos valores de la variable `total`.

Answer (score 0):

Si te animas a entrar en el modo `tidy` para trabajar con los datos verás que es bastante sencillo de elaborar lo que pides. Suponiendo un ejemplo similar al tuyo:

```
df <- data.frame(mix = runif(100), 
                 total = sample(200:225, 100, replace = TRUE))
```

La forma de trabajar es ir aplicando paso a paso las transformaciones de los datos que hagan falta, en este caso

- Filtrar solo los `total` de un conjunto previamente definido
- Agrupar por `total`
- Sumarizar contando la cantidad de filas por cada grupo

---

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  filter(total %in% c(213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220,221)) %>% 
  group_by(total) %>% 
  summarise(cantidad=n())

# A tibble: 9 x 2
  total cantidad
  <int>    <int>
1   213        4
2   214        3
3   215        1
4   216        3
5   217        7
6   218        1
7   219        6
8   220        2
9   221        6
```

En cuanto a *separar en objetos individuales cada conteo*, imagino que hablas de transformar cada fila en un elemento de una lista, cosa que puede hacer aplicando el verbo `group_split()`:

```
df %>% 
  filter(total %in% c(213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220,221)) %>% 
  group_by(total) %>% 
  summarise(cantidad=n()) %>% 
  group_split(total)
```

Comment: Agradezco su respuesta, ha sido muy útil. Respecto a lo último, me refería a guardar cada set de datos separados en por cada nivel (213, 214, 215, ... , 221). Podría sugerirme un ejemplo, por favor?

Comment: Consulta por favor, Dentro del código debajo de library(tidyverse), ¿Cómo podría agrupar en distintos dataframes aquellos valores que se encuentren en cada una de las filas para total y cantidad, por ejemplo, que me muestre los 4 valores para el total de 213, los 3 valores para el total de 214, y así sucesivamente.

Comment: No sé si te entendí muy bien, ¿querés generar 9 datatframes distintos para cada `total`?

Comment: Sí, ya que en mi dataframe tiene más de 100 mil valores de mix (pares de genes), así como lo presento en el dataframe que muestro al inicio, por ejemplo, de los valores de la columna mix para 221 columnas de total se encuentran 79249 veces, para 220 columnas se encuentran 34455 veces, y así sucesivamente.

Comment: Esto: `df %>% filter(total %in% c(213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220,221)) %>% group_split(total)` te divide el dataframe en una lista dónde cada elemento representa un dataframe mas pequeño correspondiente a cada `total`.

Comment: Muchas gracias, y ahora para guardarlo distintos archivos csv, debiera asignar cada valor (desde 213 al 221) en diferentes objetos?, en total tendría 9 objetos...

Comment: Fijate esto https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/339943/31764 el último código, justamente parte de una lista y salva en un archivo cada elemento, el concepto de lo que tienes que lograr es básicamente eso.

Comment: Gracias, lo reviso al momento... Saludos